# ARkit -Not able to load the bigger 3d model with ARkit update 6 in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, arkit, autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-arvr

Able to load the 3D model successfully with ARKit update 3(Mar18)
But not with the latest ARKit version

ARKit package - ForgeARKit-update-6-2018.1.unitypackage
Unity Version – 2018.2.0f2

For example, internally ARKit calls this api many times for meshes request.
only for first set of dbIds, am getting the result(dbids from 1..128)

For second request(dbIds from 129..258), am getting empty array as the api response.

Mesh request :

https://developer-api-beta.autodesk.io/modelderivative/v2/arkit//meshes/129,130,131…258

Request response:

Getting args as array[4] with values as 0

Am I missing something. Kindly share your inputs!

Same model, I tried to load with ARKit update 3, and am able to load it successfully.

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue in the server-side logic. We fixed it and as of Friday, April 12th 2019, the fix is live on *autodesk-api-beta.autodesk.io*.

Answer (score 0):

Please send your model URN to *forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com*, and we will take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have sent the model URN. Please have a look at it.